# Define Nested Form Data As Model In Swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I have an endpoint that accepts a multipart form. The form has an array of fields that are grouped together as objects:

```
metadata[type][] = 'car'
metadata[id][] = 1
metadata[metadata][][something] = foo
metadata[metadata][][something-else] = bar
```

There can be multiple metadatas in each request; I'd like to define this endpoint in my spec as one model called "metadata". However, that doesn't seem possible with swagger 2.0. My `type` should be `array` then I can declare an `items` offset, but it can only be comprised of "string", "number", "integer", "boolean", or "array".

Comment: were you able to resolve this @Logan?

Comment: @Sampada No, I ended up restructuring the api parameters to better work with Swagger.